# Valid to have a button with only the class of btn in a bootstrap site?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ive inherited a twitter bootstrap site where many of the buttons only have a class of `btn`:

```
<button class="btn">Edit</button>
```

The examples in the documentation all seem to have at least 2 classes for buttons. For example, `class="btn btn-success"`. Is just having the 1 class valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using Bootstrap v2 or have additional custom CSS for `.btn` or `<button>`, it's not valid to just have `.btn` as the only class on a button. That's why `.btn-default` is necessary. A just-`.btn` button won't display entirely correctly (e.g. it won't have full `:hover` or `:focus` styles).

Answer (score 0):

Using only `.btn` is a valid method, but not the correct way to style buttons in Twitter Bootstrap. The standard `.btn` is the initial CSS class on a button if you are wanting to style with TB. You do need this class because it gives the initial styling structure to the button. You should use a supporting class like `.btn-default` or `.btn-success` in order for the button to style properly depending on certain functions.

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

To elaborate, you are allowed to use `:hover`, `:active`, and `:focus` by default, but it will make the button very bland or generic and only have bare minimum styling added onto the button.

This code snippet below shows the rest of what `.btn` can do by itself.

```
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
          box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  opacity: .65;
}
```

You will need a supporting class in order to use all of the styling features of a button like `.btn-default` or `.btn-success`. These supporting classes will ensure that the button will work properly.

Here is a [**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/liixzKzrUi) as an example of what a button looks like with just `.btn`.

*These vanilla code snippets are taken from version 3.2.0*